# installing genghis in ubuntu 12.04 for sails js mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sails.js

hey guys im having problem installing genghis app and and i dont have background with ruby thats why i dont have any idea on whats happening. tried some examples on the internet but non of them works. I wish someone can teach me how to install it properly and solve the problem

[image]

Comment: Do you need to install Genghis in particular? There are cross-platform desktop apps (eg. [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) or [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/)) that should be more straightforward to install.

Comment: yeah.. i ended up installing rockmongo, but thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Downvote for screenshot instead of pasting the error.

Comment: And why on earth are you using Ruby 1.8? It's not supported anymore and is 2 major versions old!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use newer version of ruby. It installs without errors like these with Ruby 2.1.2.
Take a look — http://rvm.io. It's the most convenient way to install ruby and manage its versions.